# Async Images Download in a UITableView using Storyboard & ios5

Tags: iphone, uitableview, asynchronous, uiimageview, storyboard

I have a UITableView and I had like to download images asynchronously.
How can I do using using ios5 and storyboards?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the very same problem, and what I did was take SDWebImage from https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage, open up the project on its own, and manually upgrade it to Objective C ARC (Refactor --> Convert to Objective C ARC).

When it was done being converted, I added it the individual files to my project and it works like a charm. I just

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

and then in my - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method, it loks like this:

```
[cell.videoImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailURLString]];
```

Simple!