# How to load images in UITableView asynchronously without caching ios sdk?

Tags: ios, uitableview, caching, ios6

I am making a table that has images and data in each cell.

I want to load the images from a web server asynchronously without actually caching them.

Can anybody please help.?

Comment: Use this Link : https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: this might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668160/asynchronous-downloading-of-images-for-uitableview-with-gcd

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088575/load-images-into-custom-table-view-cell-asynchronously?rq=1

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993820/async-images-download-in-a-uitableview-using-storyboard-ios5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SDWebImage` to handle this . simply download the SDKs and include files in your project and after that you can import  "`UIImageView+WebCache.h`" in your .h file In the class you want to do your task , after that you can use following code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method as follows:

```
[ cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url string"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"]];
```